# (Kafka) Streams - foreach inside foreach

Tags: stream, apache-kafka-streams

I have a piece of code that iterates over a KStream and checks if a condition is met. When it is the case, it calls another method to do some other processing. The code looks like this:

```java
stream1.foreach((k, v) -> {
        if (someCondition) {
            System.out.println("Triggered Join");
            joinStreams();
        }
    }
});
```

Now, the body of `joinStreams()` method looks like the following (just for testing purposes).

```java
private static void joinStreams() {
    System.out.println("Started Join");
    stream2.foreach((k, v) -> System.out.println("OK"));
}
```

When `joinStreams()` is called, it only prints "Started Join" and hangs for ever. When I call it straightforward from `main()`, it prints "Started Join" followed by as many "OK" as there are messages in the stream (which is its normal behavior).
My question is: what might cause this weird result ? 
P.S: As I did understand, the problem is with the foreach (from `joinStreams()`) inside a foreach (of `stream1`).

Answer (score 3):

You just can't do that.

By calling things like `stream1.foreach`, you are building a stream topology. Once the whole topology is built, you start it with something like `new KafkaStreams(topology, streamingConfig).start()`.

You have to understand that the body of `foreach` will only be called when your stream processing topology is executing (being run). As a consequence, with your code, the call to `stream2.foreach` - meant to build the topology - happens after the topology was built and started, this makes no sense.

Comment: yes that solves it. I was missing these details about the topology. Thanks !